# How to link to Entityform submissions page?

Tags: entities

I am using an Entityform in a block to enable site users to submit enquiries to owners of holiday cottages. I need to be able to allow owners to view those enquiries.

Each holiday cottage has its own page and the Entityform appears on each of those pages.

I have created a submission reports view that will list the enquiries for a specific property.

I have also used Views to create a block to appear on the page of each holiday cottage, visible only to the logged-in owner of that cottage, containing a link for the owner to click on to “View enquiries”.

My problem is what link should I use to display the submissions? I have tried the link "entityform_types/manage/accommodation_contact/submissions” to be found under the ‘FORM SUBMISSIONS’ tab, but without success.

I have also read through all the documentation for Entityform that I can find as well as all issues relating to submissions here.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without success"? That is the correct link to one Entityform question submissions list. There are also Entityforms Views that you can use or clone and edit to suit a particular need. Views is probably the way to go to create a "report" for user roles that shouldn't have full admin access.

Comment: Hi, That's the link I've placed in my block for the owner to click on to "View enquiries", but when I log in as the owner of that page and click on the link I get the message "The requested page "/MySiteName/entityform_types/manage/accommodation_contact/submissions/page" could not be found." I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm at a loss to understand why.

Comment: Ah the absolute link clears it up, I thought you were not referring precisely to the path to keep it short, but you do need to use the full path to get to that page - you're missing the starting `/admin/structure`, you need to visit `http://example.com/admin/structure/entityform_types/manage/pidteam_q1/submissions`. Also check permissions for the owners user role, are they allowed to Administer site configuration? I'm guessing you don't want to allow them this, and you'll need Views for this.

Comment: @prkos That's great. Very many thanks. I knew I was doing something wrong! As you correctly surmised, I now I need to sort out Views, as I'm instead getting the message "You are not authorized to access this page." Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Entitform module comes with pre-built Views that list the Submissions. It is called Entityforms (Entityform Submission) and you can access the Page through

`/entityform-submissions/submissions/accommodation_contact/list`

or the Table where you can see submissions directly:

`/entityform-submissions/submissions/accommodation_contact/table`

Display one of these links in the Block you created for your owners:

`<a class="button" href="/entityform-submissions/submissions/accommodation_contact/table">View submissions</a>`

These Pages use the access permission `View any entityform submission` so allow your owners role this.

Comment: Yet again my thanks @prkos. I suspect you've saved me making yet more mistakes!

Comment: Is it possible to allow a user to view all submissions only for a specific entityform type?

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can do it with custom code through Rules or your own module. This issue is related to forms and not submissions, but maybe it can give you a push in the right direction: [Access to specific form submissions by role.](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform/issues/2459985). Post an issue on the module if you think this should be a feature, maybe the it would get implemented if the resources permit.